# I am getting System.BadImageFormatException : The operating system cannot run exception while running unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, badimageformatexception

I am working on a Winforms project. Currently I am facing a problem that running some of the test cases throw

```
    System.BadImageFormatException : The operating system cannot run . 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B6)
```

exception. This happens only if I run tests through NUnit. However, if I run the application through the code, it works fine.

Remoting is being used in the application. Can that be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both NUNIT and your code are compiled to the same platform - x86 or x64. The easiest thing to set the platform to 'Any CPU' 
on your code.

Comment: It is a called 'AnyCPU' not 'both' ;p

Comment: How can I check what platform NUnit was compiled to?

Comment: Just change your settings to 'any cpu' (thanks @leppie), it should work no matter how NUnit is compiled.

Comment: It is 'AnyCPU' already. It was my first hunch. But it did not work

Comment: I am working on an x86 machine. so, will it make sense to change to x64?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but in my case configuration file for application helped . This file contained following entries:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime version="v4.0" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```