# Running nunit tests involving remote objects are throwing the error The operating system cannot run . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B6)

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, .net-remoting

I am running my tests in NUnit. But while debugging I checked that the tests are failing while any remote object is accessed.
The error I am getting is

> The operating system cannot run . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B6)

What can be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue when two different versions of OpenMP are in use.

There's also an answer to a similar question: [I am getting System.BadImageFormatException : The operating system cannot run exception while running unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10926227/90475)